# The most general type of "product" of two functions in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types, type-inference, unification

I must find the most general type from given functions in Haskell, or rather find  the most general type of the "product" of two functions, if it exists. I am not sure but maybe I should use Robinson unification algorithm, but I can't understand it. I need a detailed solution, step by step, so I can understand.

Functions :

```
map :: (a → b) → [a] → [b] 
iterate :: (a → a) → a → [a]
```

How to find the most general type for

1. `map iterate`
2. `iterate map`

This is not a homework.

Comment: What do you mean by 'general'? Should the types be generalized? The transformations? Please explain.

Comment: The types should be generalized.For instance : typ(map) = typ(iterate) = typ(map iterate) or typ(iterate) = typ(map) = typ(iterate map).But i am not sure about the transformations.

Comment: Tell us what you've tried, and what prevented the attempt from succeeding.

Comment: Another thought that occurs to me: this sounds a lot like a homework question; if it is, your teacher (or teacher's assistant) would probably be willing to discuss this with you in person in great detail.

Comment: Here is what I've tried for (map iteration):
I have the parameter (a -> b) of map to the parameter (a -> a) of iteration,[a] of map to a of iteration and [b] of map to [a] of iteration applied.Both functions have same number of inputs and outputs,that's why I thought that I could apply every parameter to each other.

Type(map iteration) = (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]

It is not a homework but it's a relevant question to the examination,that's  why I've been trying to find an answer with explanation.In 2 days I have exam and I'm not sure if I can catch my professor to ask :/

Comment: What do you mean by the product of these functions? You seem to mean the results of applying each to the other, but that doesn't seem to be what you're doing in your comment.

Comment: Also, have you tried checking your intuition against the type GHCi infers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, write out explicitly all the omitted parentheses.

To derive the type of application of a function of type `a -> b` and a value of type `c`, we need to unify the types `a` and `c`, noting any resulting type equivalences. Then the type of the application is `b`, under the said equivalences. The rule is:

```
f   ::     a → b
x   ::     c
        ----------
f x ::         b      , { a ~ c }
```

To find this semi-mechanically, just align the types and note the equivalences:

```
map ::    (   a1     →     b1     ) → ([a1] → [b1]) 
iterate :: (a2 → a2) → (a2 → [a2])
          --------------------------
        { a1 ~ (a2 → a2) , b1 ~ (a2 → [a2]) }
```

So,

```
map iterate :: [a1] → [b1]
```

Substituting from the equivalences, we get

```
            :: [a2 → a2] -> [a2 → [a2]]
```

Now we can rename `a2` back to `a`, or `t`, or whatever. Your second example is similar:

```
iterate :: (   a2     →       a2     ) → (a2 → [a2])
map ::      (a1 → b1) → ([a1] → [b1]) 
           ---------------------------
        { a2 ~ a1 → b1 ,  a2 ~ [a1] → [b1] }
```

Since `a2 ~ a2`, we get `a1 → b1 ~ [a1] → [b1]`:

```
               a1  →  b1
              [a1] → [b1]
            --------------
        { a1 ~ [a1] ,  b1 ~ [b1] }
```

Both equivalences are impossible, define an infinite type. So the second example has no type in Haskell:

> *Main> :t map iterate 
>   map iterate :: [a -> a] -> [a -> [a]]  
>    
>   *Main> :t iterate map  
>     
>   :1:9:  
>       Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a ~ [a]  
>       Expected type: (a -> b) -> a -> b  
>         Actual type: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]  
>       In the first argument of 'iterate', namely 'map'  
>       In the expression: iterate map  
>     
>   :1:9:  
>       Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: b ~ [b]  
>       Expected type: (a -> b) -> a -> b  
>         Actual type: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]  
>       In the first argument of 'iterate', namely 'map'  
>       In the expression: iterate map

Comment: I'm confused now,wasn't it correct what rampion wrote?

Comment: @Vucicasena his answer is about type of functional composition of two functions (`f . g`); I show it for an application (`f g`).

Comment: My exercise was about a function application,not functional composition?

Comment: @Vucicasena that's what I thought. but you were a bit unclear on that. :) but since `(.)` is a function in its own right too, you can take this methodology and use it for a case of functional composition: `f . g === (.) f g === ((.) f) g`. If you do, you'll see that `(.)` has its own rule for types: its type is `(b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> c)`, so for `f . g` to make sense, `f` must be of type `b -> c` and `g :: a -> b`, i.e. output type of `g` must be unifyable with input type of `f`.

Answer (score 5):

Let's ask GHCi:

```
ghci> :type map . iterate
map . iterate :: (a -> a) -> [a] -> [[a]]
ghci> :type iterate . map
iterate . map :: (a -> a) -> [a] -> [[a]]
```

Let's see how it got them:

Given

```
map     :: (x -> y) -> [x] -> [y]
iterate :: (b -> b) -> b -> [b]
(.)     :: (s -> t) -> (r -> s) -> (r -> t)
```

And using `a ~ b` to mean "types `a` and `b` are equal".

Then in `map . iterate` we have

```
map :: s -> t where
 s ~ x -> y
 t ~ [x] -> [y]

iterate :: r -> s where
 r ~ b -> b
 s ~ b -> [b]

so
 x -> y ~ s ~ b -> [b]
=>
 x ~ b
 y ~ [b]
 t ~ [b] -> [[b]]
```

So `map . iterate :: (b -> b) -> [b] -> [[b]]`.

Then in `iterate . map` we have

```
iterate :: r -> s where
 s ~ b -> b
 t ~ b -> [b]

map :: s -> t where
 r ~ x -> y
 s ~ [x] -> [y]

so
 b -> b ~ s ~ [x] -> [y]
 b ~ [x]
 b ~ [y]
 x ~ y
 r ~ x -> x
 t ~ [x] -> [[x]]
```

So `iterate . map :: (x -> x) -> [x] -> [[x]]`.

While these functions have identical types, they have quite different behaviours.

- `iterate . map` will, given a function and a list of length `k`, produce an infinite list of lists of length `k`.
- `map . iterate` will, given a function and a list of length `k`, produce a list of length `k` of infinite lists.

Comment: Note that `~` is type equality? That's likely not obvious to the OP.

Comment: Also, the question seemed possibly to be talking about `iterate map` and `map iterate` rather than the compositions (it wasn't clear).

Comment: I wrote them down one more time on a paper and tried to understand what you wrote,and i finally understood it.Thanks a lot,but i have a few more questions. 
Can we also write for "r" of the first function composition map.iterate : r~ b -> [b] and then t~ [b] -> [[b]].Because you showed "r" for iterate.map but not for map.iterate thats why i was little confused. 
And second questions is,whats the difference between (a->a) and (a->b) ?

Comment: Vucicasena: Sorry about the confustion. I mentioned `r ~ b -> b` earlier when discussing the type of `iterate` in `map . iterate`, and it still holds at the end.  As for your second question, the difference between `a -> a` and `a -> b` is that the latter matches *any* function, while the former only matches automorphisms, that is, functions from a type `a` to itself.

Comment: So it's not correct to write r~b -> [b] instead of r~b -> b?And would it make difference if we had for map (a -> a) instead of (a -> b) or would we get the same result ?

Comment: Given `automap :: (a -> a) -> [a] -> [a]`, an analog of `map` with `a -> a` instead of `a-> b`, then `automap . iterate` won't compile as `a -> a` can't unify with `x -> [x]`, the type of `iterate f` for any function `f`.